# C nanosleep() not sleeping

Tags: c, sleep, milliseconds

```
void sleep_ms(long ms)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = ms * 1000000;

    nanosleep(ts, NULL);
}
```

This was working before and now it isn't. It seems to work when I debug and step through it in gdb though.

Comment: How many milliseconds is it supposed to sleep in your invocations? What is the return value of `nanosleep` in your application?

Comment: If you think it's not sleeping, pass the address of a `struct timespec` as the second argument and see what the remaining time is.  Also, **check the return value** as @mszymborski already posted.

Comment: Ah, I got a "Bad address". I had chaged something and forgot to make the timespec a pointer to pass to nanosleep. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you doing compiling code so that the wrong call (passing a `struct timespec` instead of a `struct timespec *`) was not flagged as erroneous by the compiler? You can't afford not to use every protection the compiler affords. If you're using GCC (or `clang`), seriously look at `-std=gnu11 -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra` as options. Using them will save you many embarrassments. It means you must have omitted `<time.h>`, or ignored a compiler warning. Don't do that — the compiler knows more about C than you do, and doesn't warn idly.

Comment: Also, if it was working and then was changed and broken, why didn't you use your version control system to revert to the working code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is a small project. I don't know why it compiled without errors or warnings.

Comment: And what has size got to do with it?  If you are capable of making mistakes like that, you can't afford not to give yourself the traceability that a version control system gives.